# assigning a "pointer-to-member" to self

Tags: c++, self, pointer-to-member

Is there any way to assign a pointer-to-class-member so that it points to the class itself?

This would effectively mean that the result of applying the member pointer to an instance of the class would be a reference to that very same instance.

eg:

```
struct SFoo {};

constexpr SFoo SFoo::* MP_foo = &SFoo:: MYSELF;
// Is there some syntax I can use here? --^
```

The reason I want this is I have a sorting algorithm that works on a container of elements of an arbitrary template type. The sorting key is obtained from each element using a supplied pointer-to-member.

However, I now wish to sort a container where the element is *also* the key. Thus, I need to make the member-pointer point to itself (as if the class were its own member).

There are a number of easy (and zero cost) hacks I can use (and I'm using one now), but I want to know if there's some syntactical trick I can use to get it done the *right* way - to avoid extra inelegant code.

Comment: This makes no sense. A pointer to a class member is a pointer to a class member. That's what makes it a pointer to a class member, and not a pointer to something else, like an instance of the class itself. Did I mention that it's a pointer to a class member?

Comment: You can't take address of constructor

Comment: This is a [XYproblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and I think you should better explain the Y, ie why do you need that (some sorting, yes, but what sorting exactly) and show that "easy (and zero cost) hacks" you mention. What is the problem with them? Why dont you want to use them if they are easy and zero cost?

Comment: @tobi303: 2nd question 1st: The easiest "hack" is to simply create a "wrapper" struct that contains only a SFoo member. It will suffice, it will just look weird and need explanation comments. A small problem, but I thought there's a chance someone else might have the same issue one day.

Comment: afaik assigning an pointer to an instance to a pointer to class member isnt really an issue, because its just not possible.

Comment: It's not an XY problem. The X is working fine in multiple other parts of code. I'm basically manipulating (sorting, superimposing, searching) groups of "scalar regions", eg "between 3 and 7". Typically, each region has some kind of associated data. For these I use a wrapper struct containing the region and additional data. But now I've got a situation where there's no associated data required, and it would be tidier to not use a wrapper.

Comment: it is an xy, because  "assign a pointer-to-class-member to the class itself" is what you think is the solution to your actual problem. However, instead of trying to accomplish something that (afaik) is impossible, you should tell us about the actual problem

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Unlike pointer to an instance, this is something that could easily be implemented - internally you'd just have a 0 offset value. And it wouldn't seem out of place to me - members are subsets of the class, but the class is also technically a subset of itself.

Comment: Well, it's not an XY because I was simply asking if Y was possible. If someone here came back and said "yes, but you need to use two sets of brackets and a caret", I'd be good. Since nobody has said anything like that yet I'll just move on and use the hack. I needed no help with X.

Comment: @xaxazak: It is an interesting idea (once you explained it clearly), but alas C++ has no such feature. It is amusing that one can actually declare such a pointer. But there seems to be no way of initializing it (aside from initializing it to null or using `reinterpret_cast` to force some other value into it).

Comment: Logically, there's no way that I'm aware of.  `SFoo::*` means a pointer to an entity inside `SFoo`'s scope (a member, in other words), which logically excludes the class itself (because any entity fully containing itself _within_ itself makes no sense, regardless of context; it would effectively be physics-defying infinite recursion, and make the entity infinitely large).  The closest I can think of would be taking the address of the constructor, which isn't allowed.  Mechanically, it should easily be possible, but it just wouldn't make logical sense.

Comment: Syntactically, if possible, it would likely be something like `&SFoo::this`, which would require extending the keyword's definition to allow being used as part of a pointer-to-member, even if said pointer-to-member is assigned to outside of a member function.

Comment: @JustinTime This also fails in the other direction - you can't take the address of a member of a member.  //  As for it not making logical sense - I am a subset of myself. Fortunately I'm not exploding yet :)

Comment: True, it might fail in the opposite direction; conversely, other keywords have been overloaded for semantically similar but mechanically different uses (such as `static`, which semantically limits an entity's scope to its containing entity, but mechanically 1) creates global/namespace variables which have internal instead of external linkage, 2) creates local variables which don't go out of scope when the function exits, or 3) creates class members which aren't tied to a specific instance), so it's plausible that if they wanted to allow this, they might use `this` to semantically mean

Comment: "the instance in question"; if so, then its mechanical meanings would be 1) a pointer to the instance upon which a non-static member function was called (the current meaning), and 2) the instance upon which the pointer-to-member is dereferenced (i.e. if `&SFoo::this` was allowed, and takes a class' address as a pointer-to-member, then given `SFoo sfoo` and `auto sfoo_ptr = &SFoo::this;`, `sfoo.*sfoo_ptr` would evaluate to `sfoo`.

Comment: And while you are a subset of yourself, you don't fully _contain_ yourself; if a doctor cut you open, they wouldn't find a perfect copy of you inside (which in turn, had another perfect copy inside, and so on, ad infinitum).

Comment: It's an interesting topic, but I don't think it's one that the C++ committee would look at of their own accord.  If someone could make a case for allowing it, though, then they might agree.  It just seems like it would be really limited in usefulness, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the question is not very clear (but -1 is not mine). My impression is that you are confusing the type of the object that is to be sorted (in your case this is SFoo), and the type of the sorting key. In a typical situation they are different. Ex: Users to be sorted (object) and the sorting key is the first and the last name (a pair of strings). You are not stating the type of the sorting key directly.

Syntactically `SFoo SFoo::* MP_foo` is a pointer to the instance field whose type is SFoo. C++ does not allow that because otherwise this will cause infinite recursion. This field will have SFoo filed and that inner field will need to have this field again.

Second, you are trying to initialize pointer to a data with the pointer to a function. Constructor `SFoo::SFoo` is a function. And as it is mentioned in comments, the addresses of ctors are not allowed.

One more attempt: *Applying the member pointer to an instance of the class would be a reference to that very same instance.*

Pointer to member points to a member. The object is not its member. Good or bad this is how C++ is defined.

You might try to define a wrapper class, something like:

```
struct SFoo2
{
    SFoo m_data_field;
};
```

Note that from the point of view of memory layout they will be identical. `SFoo2` can have pointer to member of type `SFoo`. I am not sure if this will work in your context, but you may give it a try.

Comment: I think the answer is just a "no". But can you tell me which part of the question isn't clear so I can fix it?  //  In the case the sorted object _is_ the key. It's like you're sorting a set of strings by their value, rather than objects containing strings. Yet my sorting code is written with member-pointers in mind.  //  SFoo::SFoo means the ctor (usually), but I felt it was the best way to convey my intention.

Comment: Made some clarifications, hopefully in the right direction.

Comment: Awarding this answer because "Pointer to member points to a member. The object is not its member. Good or bad this is how C++ is defined". Basically, I'm unconvinced there'd be anything wrong with allowing it (the self-referencing and self-recursiveness isn't a problem AFAICT), but as it stands it's not implemented.